# WordPress Display image where path is custom post type field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type and the image path is a field. However, when I do something as such the below code it doesn't display. The path is in the database, I confirmed:

```
    <?php $imgurl =  $fields['wpcf-portrait'][0]; ?>
    <img src="<?php $imgurl; ?>">
```

I've tried a few different things but when I inspect element is just says "null" where the src url is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "echo" the path.

The correct code for this would be:

```
<?php $imgurl =  $fields['wpcf-portrait'][0]; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $imgurl; ?>">
```

Comment: Wow, don't know how I missed the echo. What a dummy.

Comment: No worries! Happens to everyone sometime!

Comment: Marked as the correct answer. Thanks for the obvious. Much appreciated.